# Font size control of LateX previews in Org files

Tags: org-mode, latex

I love the ability to [preview LateX fragments](http://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html#Previewing-LaTeX-fragments) in Org-mode. With two easy shortcuts one can turn them on and off on-demand:

- Turning previewing ON: `C-c C-x, C-l`
- Turning previewing OFF: `C-c C-c`

One problem I encounter often is that the preview has a small font size. Is there any way to control it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can customize the variable `org-format-latex-options` to increase `:scale`.

See the Org Manual, [11.7.4 Previewing LaTeX fragments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html).

Comment: Do you know whether there is a way to change the background color of the latex fragments? It's slightly different from my Emacs background color, which bugs me out a bit...

Comment: @pfincent  with C-h v org-format-latex-options you can see a few options in Value some of which mention background. I have not tried to change the background but maybe some of those options could help.

Comment: @pfincent for example this answer looks like it could help ( I just saw the code I did not test it) https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74196/43678

Answer (score 30):

Expanding Constantine's answer.

You can use `C-h v org-format-latex-options RET` to understand what can be changed in this variable. One of the options is the scale. In the help page in Emacs you can click to change the value of the scale to `2.0`, for example, so that the equations look bigger when you run `C-c C-x C-l`.

Alternatively, you can add the following to your `init.el` file:

```
(setq org-format-latex-options (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 2.0))
```

Which also increases the scale.

Comment: Don't know if others are having this issue, but it doesn't work using this elisp snippet. I have this in my setup, which works for me: `(after! org (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.75)`

Comment: @EdwardGrefenstette minor addition: you're going to need an extra closing parenthesis at the end of your code snippet, otherwise Emacs reports an end-of-line error