# Background color of LaTeX fragments in Org mode

Tags: latex, colors, org-mode

How can I control the background color of my LaTex fragments in Org-mode?

I am using the `badwolf-theme` package, and this is what I get:

[image]

I would like the background color of my formulas to match the background color of my org buffer.

Here are my current `org-format-latex-options`:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried tweaking `org-format-latex-options`?

Comment: @JeanPierre I updated the OP. Background seems to be set to `default`. Not sure if there is a different option to control this.

Comment: Maybe try setting it to `auto`?

Comment: This works for me with the default value of org-format-latex-options, which are the same as yours. Maybe something in the badwolf-theme causes the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before, sometimes deleting the `ltximg` folder helps reset things from the previous theme.

Comment: in case anyone doesn‘t know where to look, the ltximg files are in „~/.emacs.d/.local/cache/org-latex“

Comment: @pfincent be aware that the folder for the ltximg-files is configured by the variable `org-latex-preview-ltxpng-directory`; depending on the user's configuration, this variable might also point to some other place.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (in my case it was the foreground-setting that I couldn't control appropriately). I was able to fix it by employing `xcolor` in the conversion process.

Put this in your `init.el` and execute it by pressing `C-M-x` or by restarting emacs:

```
;; fix color handling in org-preview-latex-fragment
(let ((dvipng--plist (alist-get 'dvipng org-preview-latex-process-alist)))
  (plist-put dvipng--plist :use-xcolor t)
  (plist-put dvipng--plist :image-converter '("dvipng -D %D -T tight -o %O %f")))
```

Then simply recreate your images (delete the folder `ltximg`).

Comment: I get the error: „void-variable org-preview-latex-process-alist“

Comment: Hi @pfincent, how did you execute the expression that I suggested - in `init.el` or manually with `C-M-x`? In `init.el`, please try to wrap my expression inside a `(with-eval-after-load 'org <my-code-here>)`-statement. Maybe `org` has not been loaded yet when the code in your `init.el` is executed. Or, simply execute my expression manually (`C-M-x`), **after** you've opened an org-document. Does this fix your issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is now a solution to this in later versions of org-mode:  https://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg130709.html

To get true transparent backgrounds in the generated fragments, set

```
(plist-put org-format-latex-options :background "Transparent")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the `:background` from default to `"Black"`

Somehow my `:foreground` default got changed from white to black and it was really annoying.  Note that it's expecting a `stringp` so quotes are needed.  You might be able to put hex string in there.  Haven't tried myself.