# Orgmode Latex Preview: Change Font Color

Tags: org-mode, colors, preview-latex

In Org mode we can use `C-c C-x C-l` to preview LaTeX equations in the text.

I am using a theme that makes it hard to read the equation in the default font color, and I want to avoid changing the scale to make it more readable.

**Question:** How can I change the font color used when previewing LaTeX equations within Org mode with `C-c C-x C-l`?

**Related Question:** Is there a preamble that is used to generate the preview equations with `C-c C-x C-l`? If so, how can I change it?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2):

To change the font color you can customize the variable `org-format-latex-options`, specifically the `foreground`, for example to `"whitesmoke"`.

Maybe you also have to pay attention to [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44693/8758)

Comment: I am trying to make this work, but the link you pointed me to uses `dvipng`, but I am using `svg` images. Do you know what I would have to change?

Comment: I set the value of `:foreground` to `"whitesmoke"`, but when I preview a table it just does not change the color. I tried changing the value of all other properties in `org-format-latex-options`, but nothing seems to be changing.

Answer (score 1):

The preamble is in `org-format-latex-header`. You can customize it via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-format-latex-header` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

For red equations (as an example) add `\AtBeginDocument{\color{red}}` at the end of the header lines. Apply and save the option.